# PHP Regex - How to identify and replace keywords within greater-than/less-than symbols?

Tags: php, regex

I have a string of text ($contents) containing various XML-style tags that I would like to convert to the corresponding value in the key-value pair array ($tagArray).

```
$contents = "<text>Text element</text><break><list><bullet>Bullet text</bullet></list>";

$tagArray = array(
"image" => "img",
"title" => "h1",
"text" => "p",
"break" => "br",
"list" => "ul",
"subtitle" => "h2",
"bullet" => "li",
);

$keys = array_keys($tagArray);

for($i=0; $i < count($keys); ++$i) {

    $re = '#<' . $keys[$i] . '>(.*?)</' . $keys[$i] . '>#';
    $replaced_tags = preg_replace($re, $tagArray[$keys[$i]] , $contents);

    echo $replaced_tags
}
```

My goal output for $replaced_tags is:

```
<p>Text element</p><break><ul><li>Bullet text</li></ul>
```

I will have to handle break separately as it does not contain a closing bracket in the $contents string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it. We use [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to generate an array of patterns and replacements and pass that to [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php). The patterns contain an optional `/` so they can match closing as well as opening tags. This is replicated in the replacement by using `$1` in the replacement string.

```
$from = array_map(function ($v) { return "#<(/?)$v>#"; }, array_keys($tagArray));
$to = array_map(function ($v) { return "<\$1$v>"; }, $tagArray);
echo preg_replace($from, $to, $contents);
```

Output:

```
<p>Text element</p><br><ul><li>Bullet text</li></ul>
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/FD3EA)

Comment: Thank you Nick! Much appreciated. Very concise and easy to understand :)